# Tkinter menu is not appearing on MacOS 11.2.2

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-menu

I am trying to create an application to show real-time data in a study on electrical systems. The menu will be used to open information on history of each of the graphs shown on the "front page" and will also include a quit option. When I create the menu and add a couple items to it, it does not show up when I run the application. Unfortunately in my searches, all the alternatives I have tried do not show up either.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


class PicoGridInterfacing(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.grid()
        menubar = Menu(root)
        menu = Menu(menubar)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="Menu", menu=menu)
        menu.add_command(label="History", command=None)
        menu.add_command(label="Quit", command=root.quit)

        batteryData = Frame(root)
        batteryData.grid(row=1, column=0)
        Label(batteryData, text="Hello!").grid()


root = Tk()
root.title("Electric Power Systems Lab Pico Grid Interfacing")
app = PicoGridInterfacing(master=root)
root.mainloop()
```

Here's a screenshot of the output I see:
[Screenshot of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocoei.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: I don't get what exactly you are trying to do. Are you trying to create a drop down menu? Can you please tell me what exactly you want the program to do?

Comment: @TheLizzard Apologies, my first time using stack. I'm trying to create a drop down menu in Tkinter. As of now, the menu will only have a placeholder to view the history of data and an option to quit the application. The application itself is being used for research to show graphs. Here's a link to the mock-up of what I would like the GUI to look like - https://imgur.com/a/W7JMZOL

Comment: You never actually attached the menubar to the window - would be something like `root.config(menu=menubar)`.

Comment: @jasonharper That was it! Can't believe I must've missed that when looking through tutorials thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


class PicoGridInterfacing(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)

        # master = master # `super().__init__(master)` already does that so its useless

        # Creating the menu
        menubar = Menu(root)
        menu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=False)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="Menu", menu=menu)
        menu.add_command(label="History", command=None)
        menu.add_command(label="Quit", command=root.destroy)

        # Tell the `Tk()` that there is a menu that it need to display:
        master.config(menu=menubar)

        batteryData = Frame(self)
        batteryData.grid(row=1, column=0)
        Label(batteryData, text="Hello!").grid()


root = Tk()
root.title("Electric Power Systems Lab Pico Grid Interfacing")
app = PicoGridInterfacing(master=root)
# When you inherit from `Frame` you always what the user to call `.grid`
app.grid()
root.mainloop()
```

You need to tell the `tkinter.Tk()` that there is a menu otherwise it will ignore it. Also when inheriting from `tkinter.Frame` it's the caller's job to call `.grid` (it's convention).

Comment: This answer would be better if you added an explanation. Otherwise we have to compare your code to the original line-by-line and character-by-character to see what you changed.

Comment: @BryanOakley I thought that the comments were enough. I will an explanation to the end. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach the menu bar to the root window.

So do this: `root.config(menu=menubar)`

Comment: Next time please provide a bit of code to show OP how to do that.